# Consume a REST API and store into BigQuery

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, zoho

We are trying to ingest data from Zoho Creator which exposes data through REST APIs.

Currently we are manually running a python script which retrieves the data and converts it into an AVRO file. Then we invoke a BQ load command to load it into BigQuery as large string objects per request.

What are the options to deploy this on GCP? Looking for minimal coding/configuration options.
We are thinking of a Python operator on Composer or Cloud functions.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of the data that you get from the API and that you have to store in BigQuery? How long take the current python script?

Comment: At most a couple of MBs. The REST API sometimes responds slowly but do not expect more than 30 seconds total time. Usually a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly the same thing with Cloud Functions or Cloud Run.

- With Cloud Functions you have to wrap your script in a [Cloud Functions function pattern](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python)
- With [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python), you have to wrap your script in a function and then to deploy a webserver which call this function. Finally, you need to build a container that you can deploy on Cloud Run. It seems more boiler plate but it offers more flexibility and runtime customization.

Do you want to call it on a scheduler? User [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) for that.

---

**EDIT 1**

If you use a Cloud Composer python operator, it can also work. But I don't like this solution:

- You execute your business logic inside Composer, a workflow orchestrator. In term of separation of concern, it's not so good
- The runtime isolation isn't guaranteed. I prefer Cloud Function for that.
- If tomorrow you need to perform 100 requests in parallel, Composer isn't so scalable, Cloud Functions is.
- There are a lot of change that Cloud Functions processing will be free. Cloud Composer cost at least $400 per month. If you already have a cluster, why not, but if not....
- Cloud Run (more than Cloud Functions) is portable. if you need to deploy that elsewhere, you can. With composer you are sticky to the Python operator and you need rework to achieve the portability.

Comment: Thanks, could I also do this with a Python Operator on Cloud Composer? What would be the pro/con of each approach?

Comment: I shared my opinion on Cloud Composer. It's a great tool, but not for a such simple processing.